# Can I load a Javascript as type="module" using XHR?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, cypress

I'm using Cypress to run tests written in Javascript. Cypress has a preprocess step, which according to their docs "by default Cypress handles ES2015+, TypeScript, and CoffeeScript, using webpack to package it for the browser." (https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/plugins-guide#Preprocessors)

I'm only running tests in Chrome, which supports all the language features I'm using, such as import/export. I'd like to skip the preprocess step to save time. But if I skip it I get an error `Cannot use import statement outside a module`. After reading MDN's guide, I see how to load Javascript as a module with a script tag in the html: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

But Cypress loads my tests using an XHR and an eval(). Is there anyway to load my script with an XHR as type="module" so Chrome can use the imports and I can skip the preprocessing?

Comment: Have you looked at [dynamic imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports)?

Comment: This looks like it could work! Changing my imports to functions does not throw the error. I think it solves the general issue of loading js as modules with XHRs. Thanks.